# Авторизация в микросервисной архитектуре

Tags: python, архитектура, авторизация, proxy, kubernetes

Есть серверный проект с микросервисной архитектурой (на Докере и Кубере), большая часть кода написана в двух сервисах на Питоне с использованием AIOHTTP и Django (ещё есть сервисы с NginX: Ingress, сервер статических файлов и пара других). Я бы хотел разбить эти два сервиса на более мелкие, чтобы упростить кодовую базу и сделать её более управляемой. Тогда хотелось бы и авторизацию с проверкой аутентификации вынести в отдельный микросервис, но как это реализовать?

Ещё уточню, что суть вопроса не в методах авторизации, вроде OAuth, JWT и т.п, а конкретно в распределении ответственностей и зависимостей в архитектуре кластера.

На мой взгляд, хорошим решением был бы какой-нибудь плагин для Ingress NginX или прокси-сервер перед ним, чтобы сам этот микросервис не знал о конкретных методах, нечто вроде авторизационного middleware, которое проверяет заголовки/куки на предмет токена доступа или сессии, и вешает айдишник юзера в случае успеха.

Упрощённая версия текущей архитектуры представлена ниже:

[image: Current Architecture]

Как я представляю возможное решение, чтобы было меньше запутанных связей:

[image: Desired Architecture]

Но я не уверен, что это адекватное решение. Как минимум, этот способ лишит проект плюсов Ingress Кубера, который предоставляет классный интерфейс обновления схемы путей конфигом из консоли, но, насколько я знаю, не позволяет выполнять обработку запросов впереди себя, из-за чего придётся поднимать кастомный NginX без удобной интеграции с K8s.

Какие есть альтернативные варианты решения этой задачи в индустрии?

Я могу представить только создание одного-единственного обработчика запросов для проверки авторизации и дальнейшего делегирования запросов другим микросервисам по HTTP/RPC, уже без авторизации; Но сомневаюсь, что это хорошее решение, т.к такому прокси придётся парсить весь запрос, а потом составлять новый; плюс среди тех других микросервисов есть нагруженные экземпляры NginX как прокси к чужим АПИ, и кажется такой авторизационный прокси перед ними станет бутылочным горлышком.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Теория

Итак, что я выяснил по итогу копания в сети и полутора консультаций. Есть архитектурный паттерн **API Gateway**, который описывает точку входа в кластер, и по сути, это примерно то же, что делает *Kubernetes Ingress* и то же, до чего я дошёл в вопросе. В общем случае, это прокси-сервер, который является единственной входной точкой на кластер, который может заниматься кэшированием, защищать кластер от DDoS, поддерживать разные протоколы АПИ, манипулировать URI-путями, заведовать throttling, монетизацией, а также нужной мне авторизацией. Соответственно, внутри кластера при общении микросервисов друг с другом проблемы авторизации уже нет, все нужные аргументы будут представлены в запросах.

#### Реализация

В Kubernetes популярен *NginX Ingress*, и в нём есть поддержка Basic Auth и OAuth2; не супер, но хоть что-то. Есть для Kubernetes и альтернативные версии Ingress: *Kong, Ambassador, Traefik*, которые обладают бóльшим спектром возможностей (при этом, Kong основан на NginX).

В мире Java и Spring для этих целей есть *Spring Cloud Gateway*, который, как и K8s Ingress, предоставляет удобную возможность описывать таблицы путей в формате YAML, а также является расширяемым сервисом, позволяя легко встраивать любой метод аутентификации перед входом в кластер.

Помимо этого, многие облачные платформы предоставляют собственные сервисы с большим или меньшим функционалом, в том числе [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs), [Red Hat](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/api/what-does-an-api-gateway-do), [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/api-gateway/), [Yandex Cloud](https://cloud.yandex.ru/services/api-gateway). Однако, кажется, поддержки методов авторизации или хотя бы расширения эти сервисы не имеют, поэтому в данном вопросе не актуальны.

#### Почитать

Подробнее об API Gateway и реализациях можно найти здесь:

- [microservices.io: API Gateway pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html)
- [RedHat: What does an API gateway do?](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/api/what-does-an-api-gateway-do)
- [kubernetes.github.io: NginX Ingress External OAUTH Authentication](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/auth/oauth-external-auth/)
- [learnK8S.io: Kubernetes API Gateway](https://learnk8s.io/kubernetes-ingress-api-gateway)
- [cloud.spring.io: Spring Cloud Gateway](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/)