# API Gateway Auth на K8s Ingress + Python

Tags: python, архитектура, auth, микросервисы, kubernetes

По мотивам [прошлого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1201401/198251) про авторизацию внутри кластера микросервисов, у меня возник следующий, более конкретный вопрос. Как можно реализовать паттерн API Gateway в Kubernetes для аутентификации с Питоном? Так, чтобы можно было использовать любой метод авторизации, и другим микросервисам не надо было париться об этом вопросе.

Мой список требований/пожеланий:

1. Использовать код на Питонк для аутентификации запросов, обработки лог-ина/выхода.
2. Использовать список URL'ов из K8s Ingress или хотя бы похожий простой, но мощный YAML формат, чтобы роутинг не был встроен в код какого-либо сервиса и мог быть быстро обновлён.
3. Решение должно иметь хотя бы терпимую производительность.

Любая помощь по вопросу будет кстати

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что удалось выяснить [при помощи иностранных коллег](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64963852/5308802).

NginX умеет работать с [LDAP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDAP). В [этой статье](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-plus-authenticate-users/) описывается прооцесс, а [здесь официальный репозиторий](https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-ldap-auth) с примером конфигурации Python+LDAP+NginX для внешней аутентификации. Также [есть неофициальный пример](https://github.com/dignajar/another-ldap-auth) этого подхода.

Помимо этого, модуль NginX'a `ngx_http_auth_request_module` поддерживает более простой протокол, [есть документация](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html) и [неофициальный пример](https://github.com/UnitedTraders/nginxauthdaemon) на эту тему, а также [небольшой полуофициальный пример](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/issues/873) использования в Kubernetes Ingress.

---

В качестве альтернативы, можно использовать дополнительное ПО в качестве API Gateway в Кубере:

- [Tyk](https://tyk.io/docs/plugins/supported-languages/rich-plugins/python/custom-auth-python-tutorial/)
- [Authelia](https://github.com/authelia/authelia)